# PC goes Straight to BIOS

Tags: bios

So for the past couple of weeks my PC would occasionally boot to bios instead of windows. I was fine with this as long as it booted to Windows. But now it's only booting to bios.

I've tried unplugging my disc drive and checking if the keys were stuck. But I think it has something to do with the boot priority, as only Windows boot manager is there. I've tried resetting to default but to no avail. I have an Asus M51AD with the only change being Windows 8 being upgraded to Windows 10, although it's been Windows 10 for a while. I've had this PC for 4 years. If you need any more information just ask.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried booting from a USB drive or CD?

Comment: I don't have windows on a usb or CD, I'm assuming you can buy it at a best buy or something similar?

Comment: You can download a Windows 10 iso file, then use a program like Rufus to burn it to a flash drive. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO  http://rufus.akeo.ie/